# Element-wise Euclidian distances between 2 numpy arrays

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have two Numpy arrays, each having n rows:

```
a = [[X1a, Y1a], [X2a, Y2a], .. , [Xna, Yna]]
b = [[X1b, Y1b], [X2b, Y2b], .. , [Xnb, Ynb]]
```

How can I get a new table with the Euclidean distance of each corresponding row?

```
c = [dis(1a, 1b), dis(2a, 2b), .. , dis(na, nb)]
```

or maybe

```
c = [[dis(1a, 1b)], [dis(2a, 2b)], .. , [dis(na, nb)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
c = []
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
c.append(math.sqrt( (a[i][0]-b[i][0])**2 + (a[i][1] - b[i][1])**2))
```

This will work.
a.shape[0] will give the value of n

For inputs

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
b = np.array([[2, 1], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

You will get

```
c = [1.4142135623730951, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903]
```

Answer (score 0):

I find vectorizing is more pythonic and faster:

```
a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)
np.sqrt(np.sum((a-b)**2,axis=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of examples of using scipy's cdist, or pdist or just numpy's einsum to calculate distances.  They scale to multiple dimensions as well.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
a = np.array([[1., 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
b = np.array([[2, 1], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
cdist(a, b)
Out[14]: 
array([[  1.414,   0.000,   2.828],
       [  3.162,   2.828,   0.000],
       [  5.831,   5.657,   2.828]])
```

or

```
a = np.array([[1., 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
b = np.array([[2, 1], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = b[:, np.newaxis]
diff = a - b
np.sqrt(np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij', diff, diff))
array([[  1.414,   3.162,   5.831],
       [  0.000,   2.828,   5.657],
       [  2.828,   0.000,   2.828]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The Euclidian distance is also known as the 2 norm. `numpy.linalg.norm` will calculate this efficiently across your vectors:

```
import numpy.linalg as la

a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
b = np.array([[2, 1], [1, 2], [3, 4]])

c = la.norm(a - b, axis=1)
```